# css media query issue in browser

Tags: internet-explorer, css, media-queries

i put this css

```
@import url("large_screen.css")all;
@import url("small_screen.css")(max-width : 1024px);
```

this css files are working in chrome, mozila browsers, its working in small and large screen resolutions, but ie only rendering "large_screen.css" file only, not working in small resolution css (1024X768), how it solve this, please help!

Comment: If an old version of IE, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IE? Anythting below 9 will have problems with Media Queries. You'll have to do an IE fix within the CSS files, or load a JS file to help with rendering for lower versions.

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

Comment: Hi keoki! i used <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]--> but still not working small resolution css in ie, can u help me

Comment: IE is a tricky animal, so all I can suggest is to keep on searching. I've yet to find a solution for IE that works across all their versions (including 8). It may work for IE 9 but doesn't work for IE 8; what works for IE 8 is ignored by IE9. And you may have to do a refresh to see the content fix itself. Have you tried respond.js ? 

https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you could try:

```
@import url("small_screen.css")(max-width:1024px) and (orientation:landscape);
```

or/and

```
@import url("small_screen.css")(max-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait);
```

**EDIT**

Then i sugest to put your styles in media query.
Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Styles here */
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Styles here */
}
```